# How can I fix my chasing/attacking code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

So how the code currently works is, the enemy will find the player and move towards him. When he finds him, he will stop and then start attacking. If the player moves away though, the enemy will stop attacking and just sit there until the player comes back into range. How can I fix it so that when the player moves out of range, the enemy starts chasing again and then attacks as normal?

```
float moveSpeed = 3f;
float rotationSpeed = 3f;
float attackThreshold = 3f;   //distance within which to attack
float chaseThreshold = 10f;   //distance within which to start chasing
float giveUpThreshold = 20f;  //distance beyond which AI gives up
float attackRepeatTime = 1f;  //time between attacks
bool attacking = false;
bool chasing = false;
float attackTime;
Transform target;             //the enemy's target
Transform myTransform;        //current transform data of the enemy

void Update()
{
     //rotate to look at the player
     float distance = (target.position - myTransform.position).magnitude;
     if (chasing)
     {
         myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
     }

     //move towards the player
     if (chasing == true && attacking == false)
         myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

     //give up if too far away
     if (distance >= giveUpThreshold)
     {
         chasing = false;
     //    attacking = false;
     }

     //attack, if close enough, and if time is OK
     if (distance <= attackThreshold && Time.time >= attackTime) //if attacking we want to stop moving
     {
         //attack here
         bossAttack.Attack();
         attackTime = Time.time + attackRepeatTime;
         print("Attacking!");
         attacking = true;
       //  anim.SetTrigger("AutoAttack");
         chasing = false;
     }
     else
     {
         //not currently chasing.
         //start chasing if target comes close enough
         if (distance <= chaseThreshold)  //if he gets to chase, and then you move out of range again, he won't chase again. he will only attack if comes into range again
         {
             chasing = true;
           //  attacking = false;
             //   print("Chasing!");
         }
     }
 }
```

I think that's all the necessary relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `if (chasing == true && attacking == false)` means both chasing must be true, and attacking must be false, but attacking never gets set to false after it attacks for the first time (you've commented out all of the `attacking = false` lines).

Comment: Some of those I can't enable without adding something else because then the enemy will just continue chasing even after the threshold.

I even added in 

    if (distance >= chaseThreshold && distance <= giveUpThreshold)
            {
                attacking = false;
            }

and then uncommented 

     if (distance >= giveUpThreshold)
     {
         chasing = false;
         attacking = false;
     }

so I'm still missing it somewhere but I can't find it